# No code hints showing in eclipse/vjet

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vjet

As shown below is an image from vjets hompage.

I get codecompletion but not the yellow hintbox.
I use the latest eclipse release kepler 4.3.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at your error log and post any relevant errors.

Comment: I reinstalled my operating system and it started to work. Allthough the background was black in Ubuntu 13.04 so I had to change the tooltip color to black. Thanks for the obvious suggestion though!